# Does an Amazon Kinesis stream need to stay open in order to continue to put data into it?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, streaming, twitter-streaming-api, amazon-kinesis

I'm running a script that grabs tweets and puts them in a Kinesis stream. If I stop the script from running and wait maybe 5-10 minutes to start it again, it seems to accept the new data and returns the ShardID and SequenceNumber in a response without error.

When my consumer script tries to find/parse/consume the newly added data it's nowhere to be found but any data prior to stopping the script is still there to be consumed.

If I don't stop the script and the stream stays open this "issue" doesn't seem to happen, I just don't see this mentioned in the docs anywhere and I've seen examples where people are putting data to the stream without having a long-lived script running. eg. after submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

are you using Kinesis Stream API or Kinesis Client Library to grab data from kinesis stream?

Visit [Kinsis using API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/kinesis-using-api-java.html) and [Shard Iterator type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html#Kinesis-GetShardIterator-request-ShardIteratorType) to get more information.